# React - Forwarding props with forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-forwardref

I want to define a `LinkButton` component which will behaving like a link and look like a button.

My basic implementation complains that I need to use React.forwardRef, however I'm unsure how to do this properly, especially with prop forwarding.

Even when I just type the props as `any` I still get a complaint from the system saying the props are invalid.

I would like to know how to properly use forwardRef in this (or any, for that matter) situation.

My attempt looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react'
import styles from './styles'
import { Button, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

interface IProps {
  classes: any
  to: string
  children: string
}

const NextLink = ({ to, ...rest }: any) => <Link to={to} {...rest} />

const LinkButton = React.forwardRef((props: any, ref: any) => {
  const { classes, children, ...rest } = props // <-- ISSUE BECAUSE OF rest PROP
  return (
    <Button
      ref={ref}
      role='nextButton'
      className={classes.root}
      classes={{ disabled: classes.disabled }}
      component={NextLink}
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </Button>
  )
})
LinkButton.displayName = 'LinkButton'

export default withStyles(styles)(LinkButton)

------------

It would be called like this:

 <LinkButton to='/' color='secondary'>
    {`Go Home`}
 </LinkButton>
```

Answer (score -1):

By wrapping `NextLink` in forwardRef as well I was able to solve this.

```js
const NextLink = React.forwardRef(({ to, ...rest }: any, ref: any) => (
  <Link ref={ref} to={to} {...rest} />
))
NextLink.displayName = 'NextLink'
```